# SVG animation won't re-fire animation

Tags: svg, svg-animate, smil

i have two SVG animate's appended to a path element. I want to mouseover and have `Anim1` fire then mouseout and `Anim2` fire and I want this to be repeatable.  I'm using `begin=X.mouseover`, `begin=X.mouseleave` and `fill="freeze"`.

It works well the first time around; so mouseover `Anim1` fires, mouseleave `Anim2` fires.
But then it will only ever fire `Anim1` on mouseover and `Anim2` will never fire again (or at least I can't see it doing any animation).

The animations are paths do I'm animating attribute `d`.  I've tried in Chrome and Opera, same result.

```
<path class="js-sector-rollover" id="sector1" x="400" y="431" fill="#7a596a" stroke="#3a596a" d="REMOVED">
    <animate id="animOut" attributeName="d" begin="sector1.mouseover" dur="1.2s"
             from="REMOVED" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1" 
             keyTimes="0;1" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"></animate>
    <animate id="animIn" attributeName="d" begin="sector1.mouseout" dur="1.2s"
             from="REMOVED" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1" 
             keyTimes="0;1" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"></animate>
</path>
```

I have removed the actual paths from the code block to make it easier to read.

I've also tried using `beginElement` & `endElement`, with the same result.

thanks for looking..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `end` attribute to finish the opposite animation when the other animation starts.